# Issue with VueJS updated function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following method that I need to run on route load. I have tried calling it from `updated` but it's not working. I have included the ESLint error as well.

```
methods: {
  getDeals (key, cb) {
    this.dealsRel.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
      let dealRef = this.dealsRef.child(snap.key)
      dealRef.once('value', cb)
    })
  }
},
updated: {
  getDeals (this.finalItem, snap => {
    var snapVal = snap.val()
    this.deals.push(snapVal)
    console.log(this.deals)
  })
}
```

And the ESLint error.

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token

  31 |   },
  32 |   updated: {
  33 |     getDeals (this.finalItem, snap => {
     |               ^
  34 |       var snapVal = snap.val()
  35 |       this.deals.push(snapVal)
```

I'm sure that this is just me formatting this wrong. But not sure how to make this work.

Comment: `updated` should be a function, not an object.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! I can't believe I missed that. I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updated` hook should be a function, not an object.